# autocomplete html tags in strings in Visual Studio code?

Tags: javascript, html, string

Is this possible in Visual Studio? I'm following a Wes Bos tutorial and while he's typing html in backticks (therefore in a string) in javascript, the html end tags autocomplete.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.lit-html) ?

It allows syntax highlighting and auto completion inside tagged template strings.

Answer (score 1):

I found [bierner.lit-html](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.lit-html) works perfectly.

I tried [Tobermory.es6-string-html](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tobermory.es6-string-html) too but this only gives syntax highlighting, not autocompletion.

Note that both require you to prefix your html strings with a special comment, or `html`:

```js
class DashboardView extends View {
  __html__ = html`
    <div class="mt-8 px-2 text-center">
      Look, syntax highlighting!
    </div>
  `
}
```

Don't worry about the `html` prefix, it doesn't interfere with your code, and is recognised in other places which handle markdown like github, and as you can see, stackoverflow:

```js
class DashboardView extends View {
  __html__ = `
    <div class="mt-8 px-2 text-center">
      No syntax highlighting :-(
    </div>
  `
}
```

And the cherry on the cake is that other plugins which operate on HTML such as [bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss) which adds tailwindcss class intellisense also work:

[image]

Comment: lit-html autocomplete doesn't work anymore ...